# How to include a input in a label in a querySelector() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, label

I am trying to construct a personality quiz for my school project. Everything was working fine until I decided that I want the inputs for the radio buttons to be just pictures. The problem is that I am not sure how to save the selected choice and its value, in order to calculate the result.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="simplequiz">
    <h3>What's your favourite colour palette?</h3>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="colour" class="a" value="-1" />
        <label for="p">
            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Gothic colour palette" style="width: 200px">
        </label>
    </p>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" onClick="submitSimpleQuiz()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#simplequiz label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#simplequiz label:hover {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#simplequiz label img {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
function submitSimpleQuiz() {
    "use strict";
    var colour = praseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "colour"]:checked').value);

    var total = colour;

    if (total < 0) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Goth";
        document.getElementById("simplequiz").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Minimalistic";
        document.getElementById("simplequiz").style.display = "none";
    }
}

$('#simplequiz input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#simplequiz label').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

This is just one question and answer but essentially all the answers should add up to an outcome which will display a personality description. I don't know why the button for submitting doesn't work anymore.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

I am only new to coding, but I tried including the label into the javascript and also changing the layout of the HTML so that the input is included in the label tag.

Comment: `var colour = praseInt(…` : You must want to type `parseInt(…` !

Answer (score 0):

As I am sure you won't stop with only 1 question, here is a working snippet in which you can add more questions easily:

```js
function submitSimpleQuiz() {
  "use strict";
  var total = 0;
  var answer = ""; // Added, just because… (see below)

  // Easy selection, now! That counts only "selected" inputs!
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#simplequiz .selected input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
  }

  if (total < 0) {
    answer = "Goth";
  } else {
    answer = "Minimalistic";
  }

  // Moved outside of the if to only have these instructions one time
  document.getElementById("simplequiz").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
}

// Your other code, I haven't touched it. Promise.
$('#simplequiz input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#simplequiz label').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.input_hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#simplequiz label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#simplequiz label:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

#simplequiz label img {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="simplequiz">
  <h3>What's your favourite colour palette?</h3>
  <p>
    <!-- Modified order -->
    <label for="p">
      <input type="radio" name="colour" class="a" value="-1" />
      <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Gothic colour palette" style="width: 200px">
    </label>
    <!-- Added another one below -->
    <label for="p">
      <input type="radio" name="colour" class="a" value="1" />
      <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Minimal colour palette" style="width: 200px">
    </label>
  </p>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" onClick="submitSimpleQuiz()">Submit</button>
</div>
<!-- Added "answer" -->
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Anyway, I've got a few remarks, here:
⋅ Your function `submitSimpleQuiz` is in JavaScript only, whereas your other code is in jQuery. You should choose what you want to use!
⋅ I moved the `input`s in your `label`s to make it easier to select them.
⋅ Why are you using `input`s if you're hiding them, and can't/don't check them?!…

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove line :
$('#simplequiz input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
Or you  need to modify the line:
var colour = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "colour"]:checked').value);
Because if you uncheck radiobutton you can't get the value. And You have to use parseInt not praseInt. it's an error.

Answer (score -1):

**First** off all you need to import Jquery for using Jquery function $.

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Second** it is parseInt not praseInt.

**Third:**
use this piece of code instead of yours:

```
var colour = parseInt(document.querySelector("div#simplequiz input[name = 'colour']").value);
```

**Fourth:**
for your script to work correctly your javasScript should be -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitSimpleQuiz(){
"use strict";
var colour = parseInt(document.querySelector("div#simplequiz input[name = 'colour']").value);

if (document.querySelector("div#simplequiz input[name = 'colour']").checked) {
    colour = 0;
}

var total =  colour;

if (total < 0) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Goth";
    document.getElementById("simplequiz").style.display = "none";
}
else 
{
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Minimalistic";
    document.getElementById("simplequiz").style.display = "none";
}
}

$('#simplequiz input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#simplequiz label').click(function() {
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should make a snippet of this. You'll see it doesn't work!